# Implementing a disconnecting feature

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

So, let's say I have a client, and to respond to server messages, the client must have a function that listens for them, like in my code:

```
int Client::loop(void *data)
{
Client *instance = (Client*)data;
for (;;)
{
    boost::array<unsigned char, PACKET_LENGTH> buf;
    boost::system::error_code error;
    // Read any incoming package
    size_t len = instance->socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);

    if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
    {
        // Connection closed, return
        return 0;
    }

    DataHeader header = static_cast<DataHeader>(buf[0]);

    switch (header) // Let's see which type of packet the server is sending.
    {
        case GTREG: // Server is sending a GTREG response.
            instance->getRegionResponse(buf);
            break;
        case PLOBJ: // Server is sending a PLOBJ response.
            instance->placeObjResponse(buf);
            break;
        case MOVPL: // WIP.
            break;
        case SYOBJ: // Server is sending an object that other player placed.
            instance->syncObj(buf);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

This function is made a thread by [SDL](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateThread), so that the main process of my program can do work without having to listen to the server. Now, at some point in time, I'll want to close the program, and to do so, I have to disconnect the listening socket.

This "closing function" is called by the main process of my program, so it somehow needs to tell the client thread to shutdown before closing.

Now, how do I do that? I've tried a function like this:

```
void Client::disconnect()
{
    boost::system::error_code error;
    socket.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, error);
    socket.close();
}
```

However, using it crashes the application with an error.

Is there something I'm missing? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You should shutdown the socket, then wait for the thread to terminate before closing the socket.

Comment: Added `SDL_WaitThread` after the `client.disconnect` function. -- Still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to put the wait between `shutdown` and `close`

Comment: Also, it's strange because the error occurs *after* the `return 0` instruction of `int main`

Comment: do you get a callstack? that can help diagnose what code is responsible for the crash

Comment: It's all external code: `kernel32.dll` and `wblind.dll`

Comment: it sounds like things are being stored in global variables that reference things that are no longer valid after main exits

Comment: But those global variables don't matter as long as they're not used after main exits, don't they?

Comment: Their destructors may do something that causes problems. Ideally there would be no globals, but `std::optional<>` can help in a pinch

Comment: Sounds like there' s an other thread not joined. Might be global or local to `main`